# R there any more elegant solutions to add columns into multiple data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, apply

I have been raking my right brain trying to figure out how to reduce the amount of code needed to

- change one column in a list of data frames from integer to character
- set a data.table key for all data frames
- add a column of constants to a set of data frames based on the the data frame name

Here's my code. I know there has to be a better way.

## modify column from integer to character

```
MERGED1996.97.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED1996.97.PP$OPEID)
MERGED1997.98.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED1997.98.PP$OPEID)
MERGED1998.99.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED1998.99.PP$OPEID)
MERGED1999.00.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED1999.00.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2000.01.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2000.01.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2001.02.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2001.02.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2002.03.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2002.03.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2003.04.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2003.04.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2004.05.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2004.05.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2005.06.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2005.06.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2006.07.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2006.07.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2007.08.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2007.08.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2008.09.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2008.09.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2009.10.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2009.10.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2010.11.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2010.11.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2011.12.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2011.12.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2012.13.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2012.13.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2013.14.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2013.14.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2014.15.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2014.15.PP$OPEID)
MERGED2015.16.PP$OPEID<-as.character(MERGED2015.16.PP$OPEID)
```

## setkey

```
setkey(MERGED199<-, "OPEas.character(
setkey(MERGED199<-, "OPEas.character(
setkey(MERGED199<-, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED1999.00.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2000.01.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2001.02.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2002.03.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2003.04.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2004.05.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2005.06.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2006.07.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2007.08.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2008.09.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2009.10.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2010.11.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2011.12.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2012.13.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2013.14.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2014.15.PP, "OPEID")
setkey(MERGED2015.16.PP, "OPEID")
```

## add column

```
MERGED1996.97.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED1996.97.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED1997.98.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED1997.98.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED1998.99.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED1998.99.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED1999.00.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED1999.00.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2000.01.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2000.01.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2001.02.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2001.02.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2002.03.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2002.03.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2003.04.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2003.04.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2004.05.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2004.05.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2005.06.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2005.06.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2006.07.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2006.07.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2007.08.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2007.08.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2008.09.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2008.09.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2009.10.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2009.10.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2010.11.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2010.11.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2011.12.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2011.12.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2012.13.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2012.13.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2013.14.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2013.14.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2014.15.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2014.15.PP))), 9,12)]
MERGED2015.16.PP[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(MERGED2015.16.PP))), 9,12)]
```

the code from chinsoon12 works great. Now I need to change a column name. I added

```
colnames(df)[1] <- "UNITID"
```

to the code

```
lapply(dfLs, function(nm) {
df <- get(nm)
setDT(df)[, OPEID := as.character(OPEID)]
setkeyv(df, "OPEID")
colnames(df)[1] <- "UNITID"
df[, ay := substr(gsub("\\.", "", nm), 9, 12)]
})
```

but it doesn't modify the name of the first column. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: try `purrr::map(list_of_dataframes, ~as.character(.x$OPEID))` to change column from integer to character. That should loop through the dataframes and make the adjustment. Then maybe `purrr::map(list_of_dataframes, ~setkey(.x, "OPEID"))` for the keys.

Comment: Use `dplyr::mutate_at` for mutating at positions, or `dplyr::mutate_if` for mutating based on a predicate

Comment: Lastly, `purrr::map(list_of_dataframes, ~.x[, ay :=substr(gsub("\\.","",deparse(substitute(.x))), 9,12)])` to change the column. I couldn't actually test this out though without data.

Answer (score 0):

The below works:

```
sapply(c('data.table', 'ggplot2', 'tictoc'), library, character.only = T, quietly = T)

set.seed(28)
nobv <- 1000 # number of observations per data.table 

l <- lapply(1:5, function(z){
  ind <- sample(x = 1:nrow(diamonds), size = nobv, replace = T)
  return(as.data.table(diamonds[ind,]))
})

# Name all the data.tables
names(l) <- LETTERS[1:length(l)]

cols_to_change <- c('carat', 'z')

# changing cols_to_change to character
lapply(l, function(z){
  z[, (cols_to_change) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = cols_to_change]
})

# set key for all data.table
key_by_cols <- c('carat', 'z')
lapply(l, function(z){
  setkeyv(z, key_by_cols)
})

# Add a name column for the data.tables 
lapply(1:length(l), function(z){
  l[[z]]$dtname <<- names(l)[z]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like:

```
dfLs <- c("MERGED1996.97.PP","MERGED1997.98.PP","MERGED1998.99.PP","MERGED1999.00.PP",
    "MERGED2000.01.PP","MERGED2001.02.PP","MERGED2002.03.PP","MERGED2003.04.PP",
    "MERGED2004.05.PP","MERGED2005.06.PP","MERGED2006.07.PP","MERGED2007.08.PP",
    "MERGED2008.09.PP","MERGED2009.10.PP","MERGED2010.11.PP","MERGED2011.12.PP",
    "MERGED2012.13.PP","MERGED2013.14.PP","MERGED2014.15.PP","MERGED2015.16.PP")

library(data.table)
lapply(dfLs, function(nm) {
    df <- get(nm)
    setDT(df)[, OPEID := as.character(OPEID)]
    setkeyv(df, "OPEID")
    df[, ay := substr(gsub("\\.", "", nm), 9, 12)]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP has to deal with accounting data which are contained in 20 separate dataframes, one for each accounting year.

The OP is asking *to reduce the amount of code* needed to perform certain operations.

If the dataframes all do have the same structure (number, name, type, and order of columns) I suggest to bind the data in one big data object. This will greatly simplify all operations including grouping and splitting.

```
library(data.table)
# create vector of dataframe names
df_names <- sapply(1996:2015, function(yr) sprintf("MERGED%4i.%02i.PP", yr, (yr + 1)%% 100))
# Alternatively, the names can be grabbed from the global environment
df_names <- grep("^MERGED.*PP$", ls(), value = TRUE)
# combine into one data object, prepend id column 
big <- rbindlist(mget(df_names), idcol = "df_name")
big
```

> ```
>              df_name     V1  OPEID         V3
>               <char> <fctr>  <num>      <num>
>  1: MERGED1996.97.PP      C 199601  0.2774292
>  2: MERGED1996.97.PP      P 199602  1.0844412
>  3: MERGED1997.98.PP      A 199701  0.4291247
>  4: MERGED1997.98.PP      F 199702  0.5060559
>  5: MERGED1998.99.PP      H 199801 -0.5466319
>  6: MERGED1998.99.PP      X 199802 -0.5644520
> ---                                          
> 35: MERGED2013.14.PP      H 201301 -1.1088896
> 36: MERGED2013.14.PP      F 201302 -1.0149620
> 37: MERGED2014.15.PP      L 201401  0.5630558
> 38: MERGED2014.15.PP      A 201402  1.6478175
> 39: MERGED2015.16.PP      F 201501  1.6059096
> 40: MERGED2015.16.PP      W 201502 -1.1578085
> ```

Now we can perform thre requested operations

```
# change type of OPEID column
big[, OPEID := as.character(OPEID)]
# rename second column (used to be first column before rbindlist())
setnames(BIG, 2, "UNITID")
# append column with accounting year id
big[, ay := substr(gsub("\\.", "", df_name), 9, 12)]
big[]
```

> ```
>              df_name UNITID  OPEID         V3     ay
>               <char> <fctr>  <num>      <num> <char>
>  1: MERGED1996.97.PP      C 199601  0.2774292   9697
>  2: MERGED1996.97.PP      P 199602  1.0844412   9697
>  3: MERGED1997.98.PP      A 199701  0.4291247   9798
>  4: MERGED1997.98.PP      F 199702  0.5060559   9798
>  5: MERGED1998.99.PP      H 199801 -0.5466319   9899
>  6: MERGED1998.99.PP      X 199802 -0.5644520   9899
> ---                                                 
> 35: MERGED2013.14.PP      H 201301 -1.1088896   1314
> 36: MERGED2013.14.PP      F 201302 -1.0149620   1314
> 37: MERGED2014.15.PP      L 201401  0.5630558   1415
> 38: MERGED2014.15.PP      A 201402  1.6478175   1415
> 39: MERGED2015.16.PP      F 201501  1.6059096   1516
> 40: MERGED2015.16.PP      W 201502 -1.1578085   1516
> ```

Note that I have not called `setkey()` as it is no longer required for joining due to the `on =` syntax and secondary indices.

#### Reproducible data

**Warning:** The code below will create 20 dataframes in the global environment.

```
set.seed(1234L)
for (yr in 1996:2015) {
  nm <- sprintf("MERGED%4i.%02i.PP", yr, (yr + 1L) %% 100L)
  tmp <- data.frame(V1 = sample(LETTERS, 2L), OPEID = 100* yr + 1:2, V3 = rnorm(2L))
  assign(nm, tmp)
}

ls()
```

> ```
>  [1] "big"              "df_names"         "MERGED1996.97.PP" "MERGED1997.98.PP" "MERGED1998.99.PP" "MERGED1999.00.PP"
>  [7] "MERGED2000.01.PP" "MERGED2001.02.PP" "MERGED2002.03.PP" "MERGED2003.04.PP" "MERGED2004.05.PP" "MERGED2005.06.PP"
> [13] "MERGED2006.07.PP" "MERGED2007.08.PP" "MERGED2008.09.PP" "MERGED2009.10.PP" "MERGED2010.11.PP" "MERGED2011.12.PP"
> [19] "MERGED2012.13.PP" "MERGED2013.14.PP" "MERGED2014.15.PP" "MERGED2015.16.PP" "nm"               "tmp"             
> [25] "yr"
> ```